# What are the qualifications for a religious figure to be called "Yati"?

Tags: title

Yati Narsinghanand Saraswati is currently in the news.  How is this title "Yati" conferred"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Hinduism, we have the four orders of life viz:- Brahmacharya (the student phase), Garhastya (householder), Vanprastha (forest dwellers) and Sannyasa (hermits or one who has renounced).

And, Yati or Yatin basically refers to one who is a Sannyasi (hermit), one who is living in the last Ashrama/phase of life.

From Daksha Smriti's Chapter 1 we get the following relevant verses:

> A Brahmacharin (religious student), a Grihastha (householder), a
> Vanaprastha (forest-recluse) and a Yatin (hermit) for all these,
> Daksha wrote his Institutes. (3)
>
> The three orders should be followed in due succession, and not in a
> reverse course. There is none more sinful than he who follows them in
> a reverse order. (12)
>
> A Brakmacharin is marked by a girdle, a black antelope skin and a
> staff ; a householder, by the sacrifices for the Deities, etc.; and a
> forest-recluse, by the presence of nails and hairs. And a Yatin [is
> known] by a threefold staff. These are the different characteristic
> marks. (13)

The following Manu Smriti verse has the word Yati in it, again referring to the dwellers of the 4th order. But the word is translated as ascetic. Vanaprasthi is translated here as hermit.

> etat saucham grihasthanam dvigunam brahma-charinam |
>  trigunam syad
> vanasthanam **yatinam** tu chaturgunam ||
>
> 5.137. Such is the purification ordained for householders; (it shall be) double for students, treble for hermits, but quadruple for
> ascetics.

Comment: Is the title conferred formally?  I asked another Q about tridandis. @rickross

Comment: No, one who lives in the 4th order is known as Yati, just like one dwelling in the first order is called a Brahmacahri @SK